# Rails 4: undefined method `where' for Array:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

My understanding was that Rails 4 (using 4.2.5) supported using a .where() operator on arrays.

However, the line 3 of the code below (in which Author belongs to User and has many Publications) throws `NoMethodError: undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x007fd8be73e850>`.

```
@authors = current_user.authors
@pubs = @authors.map(&:publications).flatten.uniq
@scoped = @pubs.where(name: "Publication")
```

I originally thought that it may be down to the `.flatten` part, but removing it doesn't make any difference. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: hmm if you're getting the error, then it's pretty conclusive that rails 4.2.5 doesn't have that.  i can't find anything on the release notes about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has never been a where method on the Array Class. However, what you want to do can be achieved with scopes.

```
Publication.where(name: 'Publication').joins(:authors).merge(current_user.authors)
```

That is just a guess based on your method's and naming. Im not positive you have these other relations however, so you may need to tweak it a bit.